# How to disable "--allow-unauthenticated" flag of existing gcp cloud function?

Tags: python, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

A long back when I created GCP cloud function, the "--allow-unauthenticated" was checked. It means my cloud function has public access. Now I want to update my cloud function with authenticated invocation. I tried redeploying my cloud function by removing "--allow-unauthenticated" but still on console it is showing Authentication = "Allow unauthenticated". I referred some stackoverflow articles, they are suggesting to delete the cloud function and create new one without "--allow-unauthenticated" flag. But I do not want to delete my existing cloud function since it is live in production environment.

Is there any other way to disable "--allow-unauthenticated" flag of GCP cloud function.

This is the CLI command I am using to deploy my cloud function:

```
gcloud functions deploy data-generation --region europe-west1 --entry-point main --runtime python37 --env-vars-file env.yaml --trigger-http --service-account [SA-name]@[project-name].iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "Permissions" tab for the function, remove the permission which gives the `allUsers` member the "Cloud Functions Invoker" role.

Answer (score 4):

In addition of Dustin answer, you can perform

- Delete current allUsers permission on your function. Keep your current function version

```
gcloud functions remove-iam-policy-binding --member=allUsers --role=roles/cloudfunctions.invoker data-generation
```

- Deploy a new function version

```
gcloud functions deploy data-generation --no-allow-unauthenticated --region..........
```